# node.js: How to edit xml file while preserving spaces tabs and comments

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I'm new to `Node.js` and I'm looking for `XML parser` to edit XML files in place - while preserving everything in the file (comments, spaces, tabs, etc..)

Searched and tried to use some libraries like `xml2js` but it seems that it won't preserve any comments.

Thanks!